# Can a reviewer add their signature to a specific git commit?

Tags: git, commit, gnupg

If I want to ensure each commit in a git repository has been reviewed by the author and a second (or even third) person, is it possible to have a git commit signed multiple times?

(If not I'd imagine the next best thing is to add subsequent, empty, signed commits, but that seems a bit messy).

Comment: What do you mean by a `signed` commit? Multiple authors/committers? `--signoff` used? GPG signed? `Reviewed-by` added to the commit message?

Comment: GPG signatures.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, and that it makes sense for that matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hash ID of a commit depends exquisitely on every single byte inside that commit, *including* any signatures (GPG or otherwise).  You can GPG-sign a separate *tag*—an annotated tag object that refers to the commit by the commit's hash ID—and each reviewer could do that, but if a reviewer's GPG signature is to be added to the commit, the result is a new and different commit with a new and different hash ID.

The existing, now-out-of-date, commit, which does not have the new signature, continues to exist under its existing hash ID.  If you get all other *names*—branch and/or tag names, mainly—to stop *using* that commit's hash ID, and don't use any commits that have that commit as their parent, the old commit will eventually be garbage collected.  That's another path by which this can be implemented: basically everyone makes some throwaway commit(s) in order to build up the eventual, final commit with all the signatures. As the more-signed commits are added to the repository, everyone involved throws away their throwaway earlier commit (by just not using it any more and letting Git eventually remove it) and when the final version of the commit exists under its final hash ID, everyone can move on to add new commits.

That's a pretty heavy-weight process; it's probably better to consider some other process, such as signing tags or using `git notes`, or your own suggestion of "empty" (no difference, but signed in their messages) commits.

Comment: Please note that `git notes` is _practically_ deprecated since GitHub removed support for displaying them back in 2014: https://github.blog/2010-08-25-git-notes-display/

Yes, GitHub isn’t git, but GitHub dropping them is not a great sign for their usefulness or future

Comment: @FlorianWendelborn: yet Git itself keeps getting fancier notes handling, e.g., well after that, rebase started copying notes. So they limp on...

Comment: @Guildenstern how do you view them on GitHub and/or without cloning the repo? Care to elaborate how warning that GitHub doesn’t see a future for this feature is a "completely false statement"? I wish this platform had downvotes for comments.

Comment: It's a heavy-weight process, but can be largely handled by a git platform, which holds dev keys in escrow, and applies signatures to merge/squash commits onto a protected branch after review. This would be a way to persist code review information into a cryptographic and archive-ready state, which can still be recovered with little effort decades after code additions were made (as opposed to reverse engineering the chain of trust created by code-review metadata on a propietary platform with evolving database schemata).